# What exactly are storage units in XML?

Tags: html, xml, web, xml-parsing, markup

I am trying to understand more on the physical and logical structure of an XML document. [From the specification at W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#sec-physical-struct) describing the physical structures:

> An XML document may consist of **one or many storage units**. These are
>   called entities;...

So my question is:

1. What exactly is a storage unit referring in this context?
2. Is it used from the perspective of an XML processor and how it would store and manipulate the XML document in memory or is it referring to a persistent storage used to store the document?

Comment: I think you won't go far wrong if you read "storage unit" here as "file". They probably avoided using that term because they wanted to make it an abstraction of an operating-system file - but in my view the term "file" is quite abstract enough for the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An entity in XML and SGML represents a character stream. It can be an external entity, where the character content is accessed from another file or network (HTTP) stream, or an internal entity, which is part of the literal content of the document in which it's declared and referenced. An internal entity can be declared like this

```
<!ENTITY e "replacement text for e">
```

and then used as the `&e;` entity reference in content like this

```
<p> some text ... &e; ... other text </p>
```

such that an XML or SGML processor will replace `&e;` with `replacement text for e`. The concept of an entity is also used for other purposes.

As to the second question, the entity concept is related to "storage" of character data in external files or network streams; it doesn't refer to internal memory representations of a markup processor.

Comment: when you say "external files or network streams", is that external to the document itself?

Comment: Yes; an external entity is declared with eg. a file name or URL, and the character data content is accessed from the specified file or URL.

Comment: does that mean internal entities, like the one you declared in your example, within an XML document treated as external resources?

Comment: An entity is declared as having a name, and that name can be used in the document in the exact same way (as eg. entity reference) independently of whether it was declared for an external or internal entity.

Comment: I am trying to understand what the "storage unit", aka entities, of the physical structure of an XML document is. When talking about entities in external files the term makes sense for me but what about internal entities which, to my understanding, are also storage units. what is the specification referring by the word "storage unit" in XML document.

Comment: The "storage unit" of an internal entity is the main document since eg. the character literal `replacement text for e` in the example is contained in the main document. The point is that an internal entity can be treated as if it were stored in an external file. A document is comprised of the main entity (the main document's character data itself), plus zero or more external entities referenced from it. If the document uses only internal entities (or no entities apart from the main entity itself), it is only stored in a single entity.